# Unable to get posts to show based on category (Django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

I'm having trouble getting posts to list in their respective categories on my forum. I'm able to get the posts to list when I don't specify a category, but when I do try to specify a category, no posts are shown. For example, `{% for post in posts|slice:":4" %}` will list the 4 most recent posts. Whereas `{% for post in gen_discussion|slice:":4" %}` shows nothing.

Would anyone be able to advise a solution based on my below code?

Forum HTML:

```
<section class="container">
  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
    <h5 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0 forum-category-header">
      Recent Posts
    </h5>
    <!-- A list of recent posts will display here. Limited to 4 most recent posts -->
    {% for post in posts|slice:":4" %}
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
      <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark margin-bottom-5"
          ><a href="{% url 'forum_post_details' post.id %}"
            >{{ post.title }}</a
          ></strong
        >
        {{ post.content|truncatewords:30 }}
      </p>
      <hr />
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
    <h5 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0 forum-category-header">
      General Discussion
    </h5>
    <!-- A list of recent posts in 'General Discussion' will display here. Limited to 4 most recent posts -->
    {% for post in gen_discussion|slice:":4" %}
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
      <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark margin-bottom-5"
          ><a href="{% url 'forum_post_details' post.id %}"
            >{{ post.title }}</a
          ></strong
        >
        {{ post.content|truncatewords:30 }}
      </p>
      <hr />
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
      <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <!-- User can see all 'General Discussion' posts on a new page  -->
        <a class="view-more-option" href="{% url 'gen_discussion' %}"
          >More General Discussion </a
        ><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white rounded shadow-sm">
    <h5 class="border-bottom border-gray pb-2 mb-0 forum-category-header">
      Events
    </h5>
    <!-- A list of recent posts in 'Events' will display here. Limited to 4 most recent posts -->
    {% for post in events|slice:":4" %}
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
      <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <strong class="d-block text-gray-dark"
          ><a href="{% url 'forum_post_details' post.id %}"
            >{{post.title }}</a
          ></strong
        >
        {{ post.content|truncatewords:30 }}
      </p>
      <hr />
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <div class="media text-muted pt-3">
      <p class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-bottom border-gray">
        <!-- User can see all 'Events' posts on a new page  -->
        <a class="view-more-option" href="{% url 'events' %}">More Events </a
        ><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Forum view:

```
@login_required
def get_forum(request):
    """
    Will return a list of posts that have been published
    and render them to the 'forum.html' template
    """

    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()
                                ).order_by('-published_date')

    gen_discussion = Post.objects.filter(category='General Discussion')

    events = Post.objects.filter(category='Events')

    return render(request, 'forum.html', {'posts': posts},
                  {'events': events},
                  {'gen_discussion': gen_discussion})
```

Comment: Have you tried this ? `gen_discussion = Post.objects.filter(category__icontains='General Discussion')`

Comment: Got it resolved in the end. Thanks for your feedback anyways.

Answer (score 0):

change your vieuw to

```
gen_discussion = Post.objects.filter(category__exact='General Discussion')

events = Post.objects.filter(category__exact='Events')


return render(request, 'forum.html', {'posts': posts, 'events': events, 'gen_discussion': gen_discussion})
```

Comment: Ah, sorted it. Cheers! @houda

Comment: happy for you :)

Comment: Can you plz mark this question as answered. 10x in advance.